# @ApiParam is not working with springfox swagger 2

Tags: java, spring, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

i'm using Springfox swagger 2 for my api documentation and i have the following controller:

> HelloController.java

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.wordnik.swagger.core.Api;
import com.wordnik.swagger.core.ApiParam;

import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import springfox.documentation.annotations.ApiIgnore;


@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/hello",method = RequestMethod.GET)
@Api(value="Hello wwwww", description="this controller will say hello")


public class HelloController {
    //@ApiIgnore
    @ApiOperation("Get all products of our database")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/id", method = RequestMethod.GET)

    private String hello(@ApiParam(name = "studentId", 
              value = "The Id of the Student to be viewed", 
              required = true) 
    @PathVariable ("student") Integer studentId) {
        String name = "hello world";
      return name;
    }

}
```

so the problem is that the parameter description is not shown correctly in my swagger ui , any idea why?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is related to the fact that the `description()` method of the `@Api` annotation is deprecated and is documented as : "Not used in 1.5.X, kept for legacy support." .

This has been discussed on github for swagger : [swagger 2.0 why api description has been deprecated ?](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/1476)

The alternative would be to use [@SwaggerDefinition](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X#swaggerdefinition)

Comment: thank you for your reply,i'm using version 2.7.0 and (@ApiOperation) is working fine and the annotation doesn't shown as deprecated they are shown normally,only (@apiparam) doesn't give the right description of the parameter,is there any other annotation to change the parameter description?

Answer (score 0):

If you want description in Swagger's `@Api` you should use [tags](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X) for example:

> @Api(tags = {"external_info","user_info"})

See [grouping with tags](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/grouping-operations-with-tags/):

> you can specify description and externalDocs for each tag by using the global tags section on the root level. The tag names here should match those used in operations.

In you case

```
@Api(tags = {"hello_info"})
```

And specify tag:

```
tags:
  - name: hello_info
    description: this controller will say hello
```

or in `@SwaggerDefinition(`

```
   tags = {
            @Tag(name = "hello_info", description = "this controller will say hello")
    },
```